# Restlet + Embedded jetty + webapp

Tags: java, jetty, restlet, restlet-2.0

Just wondering if this setup is possible:

1. **Java application** running and monitoring embedded jetty server
2. **Restlet** application deployed in embedded jetty exposing RESTful API
3. Java based **webapp** (Spring, Play, whatever) deployed in embedded jetty and talking to the RESTful API via Ajax

I know that Restlet can serve a role of HTTP server via jetty connector, but this is not really what I need. What I want is servlet container (embedded jetty) run from java application and exposing two web applications: RESTful API and webapp client.

Comment: Ok, and hooooow? ;) Do I compile my Restlet app to be a *.war and then deploy it along the way with webapp? Or perhaps somehow instruct Jetty to run entry point of Restlet app to register all routers?

Comment: I would go for two war's, or just combine everything in a single war. I don't see the point in separating the functionality

Comment: One application is already ready. I just need to supplement it with user interface and embed the two into one server instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for my case it turned out that it's even easier than I thought. It will suffice to instruct Restlet to serve some static content via [this sample code](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.1/jse/api/org/restlet/resource/Directory.html):

```
Directory directory = new Directory(getContext(), "file:///user/data/files/");
Router router = new Router(getContext());
router.attach("/static/", directory);
```

This not exactly answers my question, but it solves my problem. As there were no more answers, I'm closing this issue.